# Call super in the context of this method caller

Tags: ruby

I have several methods which have similar conditional logic and I think it's reasonable to DRY them.

```
class A
  def parent1(val)
    puts "parent1 A #{val}"
  end

  def parent2(val)
    puts "parent2 A #{val}"
  end
end

class B < A
  def parent1(val)
    if val
      puts "foo"
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def parent2(val)
    if val
      puts "bar"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to create a `#puts_or_super` which would be able to call `super` of its caller? (`B#parent1` or `B#parent2`) So the code will look like this:

```
def parent1(val)
  puts_or_super(val, "foo")
end

def parent2(val)
  puts_or_super(val, "bar")
end
```

**Edit**: this works but looks insane

```
def puts_or_super(val, text)
  if val
    puts text
  else
    self.class.superclass.instance_method(caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2].to_sym).bind(self).call
  end
end
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: `super` is used for class inheritance. You use two different methods. Can you extend your example  to show, in which classes you want to use your example? And what you want to call?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to keep it simple. Both `parent1` and `parent2` are in a class which is inherited from another.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your definitions are in class `A`, and the relevant super methods are defined in class `B` so that `A` inherits from `B`.

I think you should go the other way around. Make `B` a module, and prepend `B` to `A`. Then, the definitions where you have the `"foo"`, `"bar"`, etc. would not be the super methods, and the conditions will be in the prepended module.

```
module B
  def parent1(val)
    return super if val
    ... # your original logic in super class
  end
  def parent2(val)
    return super if val
    ... # your original logic in super class
  end
end

class A
  prepend B
  def parent1(_); puts "foo" end
  def parent2(_); puts "bar" end
end
```

Comment: Maybe I provided a bad example so I decided to not answer my question but simplify the example. Sorry, but that's not what I need. Basically, I want to DRY `parent1` and `parent2` methods, especially `super` call part.